# does angular route must use different prefix?

Tags: angular

I have define two route.

> /apples---> AppleComponent,
>
> /apples/:id  ---> AppleDetailComponent,

when I visit /apples/111, it will first go into AppleComponent, and then go into AppleDetailComponent.

what should I do and it will just match /apples/:id when visit /apples/:id?

I hava also tried {pathMatch:'full'} but it doesn't work.

angular tutorial use two different route:

> /heroes
>
> /detail/:heroId

does it must use different prefix??

===update=======
@im.pankratov  I define my route exactly like yours.

finally I find the problem is **apple is null**.

```
export class AppleDetailComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(
 private appleService:AppleService,
 private route:ActivatedRoute,
 private location:Location
) {
}

@Input() apple: Apple;

ngOnInit() {
 this.route.params.switchMap((params:Params) => this.appleService.getApple(params['id']))
 .subscribe(apple => {
 this.apple = apple
 });
}
```

if i add a *ngIf='apple', the mistake will be disappeared.

```
<div class="container" *ngIf='apple'>
    <h1>{{apple.title}} {{apple.desc}}</h1>
</div>
```

how can html render after ngOnInit complete ?

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define routes correctly. For example, this is how your route configuration for a separate module could look like:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppleComponent } from './path/to/apple.component';
import { AppleDetailComponent } from './path/to/apple-detail.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'apples', children: [
      { path: '', component: AppleComponent },
      { path: ':id', component: AppleDetailComponent},
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class AppleRoutingModule { }
```

The main thing here is `routes` constant.